# WCF - Server Method failed with status code 0

Tags: javascript, c#, wcf, service

I created a WCF service and I access it through a JavaScript proxy.

The method takes two strings as parameters, and also returns a string.

I call the method in JavaScript like this - `service.checkOrderStatus(orderNumber, login,changeMessage, failMessage, null);`

And it ALWAYS goes to `failMessage` callback and says:

> The server method checkOrderStatus() failed with status code 0".

I'm sure I configured the `web.config` correctly

I tried EVERYTHING and it's still the same.

I heard from few sources that it can be happening because JavaScript doesn't wait for the WCF method to finish and return value.

How to solve this error?

Comment: And where is `checkOrderStatus` code?

Comment: The code of checkOrderStatus is in the WFC Service. The code doesn't even matter because I'm sure it works, and also even when I put nothing but simple "return "something"" there, I still get the same error. It must be some error in the communication between JavaScript proxy and the WCF Service.

Comment: If you open up the dev console of your browser and check the actual network request and response, what does that tell you?

Comment: @rene , I don't understand. Could you specify how should I check this? My browser is Google Chrome

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: @rene - ok, I did that and my console says: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:50346/OrderStatusCheckService.svc/checkOrderStatus. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405."